# Jquery Using external URIs as IDs for scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is a basic question. I have the following structure:

```
 <li id="example.org/element1"></li>
 <li id="http://example.org/element2"></li>
 <li id="example"></li>
```

I am trying to scroll to their positions when clicking certain elements. The function that scrolls is as follows:

```
var target = ...
  console.log(target);
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + target).offset().top
  }, 1000);
```

This is working fine with the ID "example", but not with the other universal IDs containing URIs:

```
example.org/element1
jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #example.org/element1


http://example.org/element2
jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #http://example.org/element2
```

I have been researching and tried options such as escaping characters and others, but nothing worked. Is there a way I can use internally such IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use data-id, instead of id, because I'm not sure what can be in id:

```
<li data-id="example.org/element1">1</li>
```

and:

```
$('[data-id="' + target + '"]')
```

Make sure it's properly escaped in case it has single or double quotes in the string

Answer (score 1):

> This is working fine with the ID "example", but not with the other
>   universal IDs containing URIs:

because your code `scrollTop: $('#' + target).offset().top` is looking for a valid element selector with an id, not just any URL.

In case of  `<li id="example.org/element1"></li>`, your jquery code translates to

```
scrollTop: $('#example.org/element1').offset().top
```

which is not the [valid id](http://xahlee.info/js/html_allowed_chars_in_attribute.html) of the element.

However, you can make it a different attribute (something like `data-id` like @Gavriel has mentioned)

```
<li data-id="example.org/element1">1</li>


console.log( $( "li[data-id='example.org/element1']" ).html() );
```

Comment: This is not really an option since there might exist "example.org/element1" and "another.com/element1"

Comment: @user1156544 you anyways shouldn't have slash in the id value, since then it doesn't form a valid selector. http://xahlee.info/js/html_allowed_chars_in_attribute.html

Comment: @user1156544 check my update post for explanation why it won't work.

Comment: The use of such IDs might be necessary to reference internally some universal elements (f.ex those from RDF). I thought there was a way to do it without HTML5 data-*, but apparently there isnt. I mark @Gavriel answer as correct since he wrote it first

Comment: @user1156544 yes that is correct. Hope you understood.